# What would happen to the orbital radius of the Earth if the radius of the Sun is decreased but without any loss of its mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

What would happen to the orbital radius of the Earth if the radius of the Sun is decreased but without any loss of its mass?

According to Newtonian gravity the acceleration due to gravity will increase when the radius is decreased? And the orbital radius will decrease. But then this seems to easy and simple. Can anybody help?

Comment: What's unclear about this question?

Comment: If you decrease the radius of the sun, there would be a pretty bad explosion and then most of the sun's mass would leave the system, afterwards the orbital radius of Earth would be greatly increased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gravitational attraction between two bodies depends on the mass of each body, and the distance between them. This increases as the product of their mass increases, and decreases exponentially as the distance between each body's *center of gravity* (aka centre of mass) increases (inverse square law). This calculation using their masses and separating distance is then multiplied by a constant to make the dimensions consistent and the numerical result match observation. Since your question says that only the radius of the sun decreases without any loss in mass, the only thing that changes is its density. Its center of gravity does not change, so the force of gravity won't change either. The only thing in your question that changes is the sun's density, and this does not have an effect on orbiting bodies. Your perception of being "easy and simple" is indeed correct.

Comment: to some limits. When the Sun will grow bigger than Earth orbital radius, it will no longer be the case. ;-)

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET - Ah, never considered the red giant (if I recall the name correctly).  I was so busy trying to make my little box look like I was a legit, viable 'answer-er' that it never occurred to me that I might try thinking outside of it!   ;-D   So now my task is to decide whether or not to make an edit appending your info.  Good to have all the pieces with the option to edit, rather than the other way around.

Comment: no need to edit, especially with the question being about shrinking :-) . Still, it's good to remind oneself the limits of the simplification "equivalent to all mass at the center ": good for astronomic distance, blatently false inside objects (the gravity decrease to 0 while going to Earth center), and approximative on Earth (spherical symmetry assumption). But all this is quite out of the OP concern :-)